# Filter Name with Starting Letter

Tags: sql

Here is my code for selecting details by checking the name given.
Here I want to do name filtering by starting letter also.. how can I do it?

```
select * from tblcustomer
where 
customername=case @customername
        when null then customername
        else @customername
```

Comment: That is SQL, not C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not C#, it's SQL.
in SQL you can use `like` clause.
ex: `select * from tblcustomer where CustomerName like 'A%'` it will display customer name start with letter `A`

**EDIT**

```
DECLARE @CustomerName varchar(200) = NULL

SELECT TOP 100 * FROM tblCustomer
WHERE CustomerName like CASE WHEN @CustomerName IS NULL THEN '%' ELSE @CustomerName + '%' END
```

Comment: How can I use like clause in else statement ?